# Couldn't find Listing without an ID ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a resource called Listings and a resource called email

listing has_many :emails 
email belongs_to :listing

I am trying to pass the listing id to email.listing_id but I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't find Listing without an ID ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EmailsController#create
```

Here is my code:

```
class EmailsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def new
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
        @email = Email.new

    end

    def create
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
        @email = Email.new(params[:email])



    end
```

from my listing show page I pass the listing.id

```
<%=link_to "Email Listing", new_email_path(:listing_id => @listing.id)
```

Email _form

```
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :message %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :listing_id, :value => @listing.id %>
  %= f.button :submit, :value=> "Send Email" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your `@listing = Listing.find(params[@email.listing_id])`, since you already have the ID you want on `@email` variable you can avoid use params again, try something like:
`@listing = Listing.find(@email.listing_id)`

Comment: Ya I did that before. The error goes away but for some reason it always passes listing_id of 1 to the create action, even though it passes listing_id 3 for example to the new action

Answer (score 0):

Please view this post for the answer:

[Couldn't find Listing without an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068311/couldnt-find-listing-without-an-id)

the issue was that my params were like this:

```
"email"=>{"email"=>"xyz@z.com",
 "message"=>"hello",
 "listing_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Send Email"}
```

Just change

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
```

to

```
@listing = Listing.find(params[:email][:listing_id])
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's because you created view for 'new' action, and while trying to enter the page you don't have any param, so basically you're execute *'Listing.find(nil)'*.

if not, try to print the value of params, and check where did the listing_id got missing.