# Couldn't find Listing without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a resource called Listings and a resource called email

listing has_many :emails 
email belongs_to :listing

I am trying to pass the listing id to email.listing_id but I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't find Listing without an ID ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EmailsController#create
```

Here is my code:

```
class EmailsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def new
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
        @email = Email.new

    end

    def create
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
        @email = Email.new(params[:email])
        @email.user_id = current_user.id


    end
```

from my listing show page I pass the listing.id

```
<%=link_to "Email Listing", new_email_path(:listing_id => @listing.id)
```

Email _form

```
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :message %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :listing_id, :value => @listing.id %>
  %= f.button :submit, :value=> "Send Email" %>
```

Params:

```
"email"=>{"email"=>"xyz@z.com",
 "message"=>"hello",
 "listing_id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Send Email"}
```

Comment: can you post the output of Listing.find(3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's easy actually.. your params is

`params[:email][:listing_id]` NOT `params[:listing_id]`.

ah, answer was deleted, in which you copy-pasted the params you are sending, so I have no longer proof that this is the case, but from what you have pasted there, it seems that params are in form

Just change

`@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])`

to

`@listing = Listing.find(params[:email][:listing_id])`

By the way, there is a lot to improve...

1st. you can use nested resource, so you will not have to care about putting hidden_input. Second, you can make a before_filter method to get proper @listing and use @listing.emails.build to set the relation correctly.

Comment: Thanks @mkk, That makes sense. Not sure why the comment got deleted.

Comment: can you share your comments on the things I can improve.

Comment: :listing_id is not nil. this is what's in my parameters: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xyz", "email"=>{"email"=>"xy@zl.com", "message"=>"hello", "listing_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Send Email"}

Comment: and if I change up the above code to something like this: -email = Email.new(params[:email] -email.user_id = current_user.id -listing = @email.listing then I don't get the error but what is saved in database is: listing_id: nil

Comment: @Benamir I have written some initial thoughts that come to my mind when I see your code, if you have any further questions let me know

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i'll make the changes.